# How can I do simple stuff with assembly?

Tags: assembly

I am trying to experiment with assembly (OS independent) by using the following code with bochs on windows machine.

```
start:
    hlt
times 510-($-start) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

This only halts the machine but I wanna start experimenting with simple stuff like Drawing dots on the screen (and coloring them later on), printing messages, loading other assembly or C applications from that simple boot loader. Where can I find help concerning that ? Would you please provide simple examples if there are no decent sources to teach such stuff ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to learn Assembly? Specifically, for someone who has experience in dynamic languages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-assembly-specifically-for-someone-who-has-experi)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this SOq:

- [What is the best way to learn Assembly? Specifically, for someone who has experience in dynamic languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-assembly-specifically-for-someone-who-has-experi)

Specifically, this is the link that might be useful to you:

- http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/

At the bottom of the last page, you have both the PDF and the code.